# How do I get this GNOME desktop in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, gnome

I have seen this version of GNOME desktop and want to install it on my computer:

[image: this version of gnome desktop and want install it on my computer]

I saw it on a YouTube video and it looks great. It looks like it is the OpenSUSE or Fedora GNOME desktop.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. As is its unclear what the question is, and its essentially a guessing game.

Answer (score 2):

What you see in the screenshot is regular Gnome desktop. It shows that particular view when you open Activities menu - the Gnome's equivalent of Unity dash or Start Menu in windows.

To get it, just run `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`. If you want full blown Ubuntu Gnome just like official installation, then run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Then on the login screen there's a Unity icon somewhere that when clicks gives a drop down with GNOME or suchlike in it